# Cells in UITableView are loading slowly

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to have a view controller with cells that look like messages.
In the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, I get the text and measure it with the following code:

```
NSStringDrawingContext *ctx = [NSStringDrawingContext new];
    NSAttributedString *aString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:message.text];
    UITextView *calculationView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    [calculationView setAttributedText:aString];
    CGRect textRect = [calculationView.text boundingRectWithSize:self.view.frame.size options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:calculationView.font} context:ctx];
    cell.messageLabel.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, MIN(textRect.size.width + 20, 240), textRect.size.height + 10);
```

This code also change the size and location of the label.
But the issue is that the size of the label changes only a second after the view loads, and not right away when the view loads.
Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: You're creating an entirely new text view every time the method is called. That's pretty inefficient. Also, if you RTFM, you'd know that the correct method to tell your tableview the sizes of your cells is in the `tableView:heightForCellAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: I am using this method as well. what I have is a custom cell with 2 labels. one label shows a message content, and therefore I don't know the size of that label. that's why I need to calculate it in every cell. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Using that method as well? What do you mean by that? And using a `static` textview for calculations would be a good way to go.

Comment: I'm using `tableView:heightForCellAtIndexPath` in order to set the height of the cell. But inside the cell I have a UILabel that it's height needs to be also determined. Can I use `tableView:heightForCellAtIndexPath` to set both (the cell and label in the cell) heights?

Comment: Your labels should have proper constraints set so that they scale properly with the cell.

Comment: But I also wish to set the label's width according to the text. where should I do that?

Comment: You're doing things wrong then. Use a collection view.

Comment: shouldn't it be simple, to set a row for each message, and then just set the label of the message content according to the size of the content? Why a collection view is better for this?

Comment: A collection view allows for variable width cells.

Comment: but I don't need to set the width of the cell. I just need to set the width of the UILabel inside my custom cell

Comment: Using a collection view WILL solve all your problems. Just research a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the [`tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:) method. The `cellForRowAtIndexPath`  method is not where you should do the height calculations.

#### Example:

```
#define FONT_SIZE 14.0f
#define CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH 320.0f
#define CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN 10.0f

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    NSString *text = [DescArr objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);
    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 100.0);
    return height; 
}
```

Comment: I am using this method as well. what I have is a custom cell with 2 labels. one label shows a message content, and therefore I don't know the size of that label. that's why I need to calculate it in every cell. Is there a better way to do it?